# Request in jQuery ($.ajax) and Angular ($http) not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get the fastest and most direct way some data from an API. Using the Postman I can so easily just giving a GET in the url (http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos) and get:

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "grupos": [
    {
      "Titulo": "A inteligência emocional do seu corpo",
      "ID": 1
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional em família",
      "ID": 2
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional em sociedade",
      "ID": 3
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional no trabalho",
      "ID": 4
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional nas férias",
      "ID": 5
    },
    {
      "Titulo": "Sua inteligência emocional no dia a dia",
      "ID": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to do a GET using jQuery or Angular, I can not. Below are the two calls and errors that I get.

1. Using jQuery

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSONP',
     url: 'http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos/',
     success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(e) {
       console.log(e);
     }
   }).done(function( data ) {
     console.log("done ", data);
   })
   .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log('erro');
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
       console.log(textStatus);
       console.log(errorThrown);
   });
   ```

> - Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}
> - erro
> - undefined
> - parsererror
> - Error: jQuery111108493785087484866_1448911631891 was not called(…)

2. Using Angular

   ```
   $http.jsonp('http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos/ListarGrupos')
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $log.error(data);
     $log.error(status);
     $log.error(headers);
     $log.error(config);
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $log.log(data);
     $log.log(status);
     $log.log(headers);
     $log.log(config);
   });
   ```

> - undefined
> - (d){b||(b=ad(a));return d?(d=b[F(d)],void 0===d&&(d=null),d):b}
> - Object {method: "JSONP", transformRequest: Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNJG.png), transformResponse: Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNJG.png), url:
>     "http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos", headers: Object}

Obs.: I can see the return, but it is presented as an error, so I can not manipulate the data. Look!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Important! I do not have access to API, so it will be welcome solutions that arrest some of the proposed methods (jQuery or Angular).

Comment: You're returning JSON, not JSONP, there's a difference

Comment: so, uh, why are you sending a JSONP request in the web page and a JSON request in postman? that's two very different data types. One results in an XHR request expecting json, and the other results in a script request expecting javascript.

Comment: I tried to use a $http.get, but the API returns me the following error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access." So I'm using JSONP.

Comment: you can't use JSONP if the cross-origin service doesn't support JSONP for the same reason you can't use XHR if the cross-origin service doesn't support CORS.

Comment: what happens if you change the dataType to JSON instead of JSONP ?

Comment: If I change the type I can not make the request. An error occurs:  "XMLHttpRequest cannot load wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8080';"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by enabling CORS in the API.

Answer (score -2):

Use $http , $q injectors and promise method in angular app

An Example can be found below

```
angular
        .module('yourApp')
        .factory('dataService', dataService);

    dataService.$injector = ['$http', '$q'];function dataSvc($http, $q) {
     var service = {
     getListGroupsSvc :getListGroupsSvc};return service;



  function getData(url) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(url)
            .then(function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result.data);
            },
                function (result) {
                    deferred.reject(result);
                });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

You can Call the above function

```
  function getListGroupsSvc(){

   var url = 'http://www.wsfebracis.com.br/Json/ListarGrupos/ListarGrupos';

   return getData(url);
   }
```